# What should my controller return in a Craft.postActionRequest

Tags: plugin-development, controller

Simple question: I made a button in my plugin settings that creates a `Craft.postActionRequest` but what should the controller return?

It does not need to return anything else than true (successful) or string (action was not successful ->  errormessage) but if I return a true or a false or anything else than a template to render I get an error...

Little example:
my template is just

```
{{ response }}
```

And my controller

```
//correct -> no error, this template is just empty
public function actionDeleteAccessToken(){
    return $this->renderTemplate('srgoogleanalytics/tools/empty', array(response => true));
}
```

but if I make something like this

```
public function actionDeleteAccessToken(){
    return true;
}
```

I receive a PHP error file not found.
What do I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking to return `true` or an error message from your controller's action, then it should probably be something like:

```
$this->returnJson(array('success' => true));
```

Or on error:

```
$this->returnErrorJson($e->getMessage());
```

`returnErrorJson` will set an `'error'` key and pass whatever mess you use as its value.